# What is wrong with this program for flat top sampling?

Tags: matlab

I made this program for flat top sampling, so instead my o/p follows the square wave!

```
t = 0:0.001:1;
m = cos(2*pi*25*t);
Vc =square(2*pi*15*t);
n = length(t);
 % this for loop is where sampling is done
 for i = 2:n
 k = i-1;
 while (Vc(i)== 1 && i<numel(Vc))
% I will be initialising y with zeros before the while loop     
y = m(k)*Vc;
 i =i+1;
 end;
 end;
```

have I made any mistake with my 'for' loop?

Comment: What exactly is "flat top sampling"?  Do you mean a Zero-Order-Hold sampling?  http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Zeroorderhold.signal.svg.  If this is, can I suggest another way of doing it?  You actually don't need `for` loops here.

Comment: Flat top sampling is like natural sampling. In this sampling techniques, the top of the samples remains constant and is equal to the instantaneous value of the message signal x(t) at the start of sampling process. Sample and hold circuit are used in this type of sampling

Comment: This image(link) will add to the information. http://dc347.4shared.com/doc/u-0RKMDN/preview_html_m17210728.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I haven't received a reply from you so let's just go with your original code.  I'm going to assume that "flat top sampling" means [Zero-Order-Hold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-order_hold) sampling.  This is a common technique in many DSPs and other hardware that processes digital signals where at each positive transition of a clock, you sample whichever amplitude is present at that point in time.  You **hold** that amplitude until the next clock cycle, then repeat the process.

There are several things wrong with your code, which I will point out below:

1. You don't initialize your output signal `y`.  In fact, inside your `while` loop, you are assigning your output to be a **single** variable instead of it being positioned inside an array.  The effect of this is that you will only remember the last point that you have sampled at which is probably not what you intended.

   With regards to initializing your output, though you don't have to for a relatively small signal, it's recommended that you pre-allocate any variables you're going to use if they are to be populated in pieces at a time.
2. You are writing a `for` loop, but then you're also changing the `for` loop iteration index inside of the `while` loop.  Changing the `for` loop index inside of the loop body is not recommended.  In fact, your MATLAB editor should give you a warning telling you that this behaviour is discouraged.  Because of the way your loop index is dynamically changing depending on what part of the clock transition you're in, I would encourage that you write a `while` loop instead.
3. You're not handling what happens when the clock cycle is in the negative transition.  If this is the case, then you need to use the amplitude from the positive transition and continue in your iterations.  Once you hit a positive transition, you then refresh what the current amplitude is, then you hold this until the next positive transition.
4. You don't need to do `m(k)*Vc` because `Vc` is already 1 in order to satisfy that `while` loop.  You can get rid of that `Vc` all together and just use `m(k)` instead.

I've also taken the liberty to clean up some unnecessary variables, and I've also placed comments in your code.  With all of the stuff I've talked about, here's what the final code looks like.  Note that I've truncated the signal to 0.5 seconds to make the signal more visibly clear.  I've also provided a plot of what the original signal, the clock signal, and the Zero-Order-Hold sampled signal looks like:

```
%// Your code
t = 0:0.001:0.5;
m = cos(2*pi*25*t);
Vc =square(2*pi*15*t);

%// Defined n here as number of points in signal
n = numel(t);

%// Pre-allocate array
y = zeros(1,n);

%// Initialize starting of loop to 2
idx = 2;

%// Start at the first amplitude of our signal
k = 1;

%// Until we reach the end of the array...
while idx < n
    %// If we see a negative value of the square, just hold
    %// onto the previous amplitude until we hit a positive one
     if Vc(idx) == -1
         y(idx) = m(k);
         idx = idx + 1; %// Go to next sample
     %// Now we've hit a positive amplitude    
     else
         k = idx - 1; %// Remember the last amplitude
         %// Until we hit a negative transition...
         while (Vc(idx) == 1 && idx < n) 
             y(idx) = m(k); %// Copy over last amplitude
             idx = idx + 1; %// Go to the next sample
         end
     end
end

%// Plot all of our relevant signals
plot(t,m,t,Vc,t,y);
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('Amplitude');
legend('Original', 'Clock', 'ZOH Sampling');
```

This is the plot I get:

[image]

---

As a minor note, there are more efficient ways to do this, but judging from your post, you wanted to ascertain why your code isn't working and not a more efficient way to compute ZOH sampling.  I'll leave that to you as an exercise, or another StackOverflow answerer if they so choose to provide a more efficient answer.

Good luck!

Comment: While this was really helpful,I modified the program a little as per my requirement.Thank you

Comment: @user3820043 - Ah ok.  All you had to do was remove that `if` condition checking if the square wave was -1.  On the negative transition, we just output 0.  Thanks for the link to flat top sampling!

Answer (score 0):

```
t = 0:0.001:1;
m = cos(2*pi*25*t);
Vc =square(2*pi*15*t);
n = length(t);
 % this for loop is where sampling is done
 for i = 2:n
end 
k = i-1;
 while (Vc(i)== 1 && i<numel(Vc))
% I will be initialising y with zeros before the while loop     
y = m(k)*Vc;
 i =i+1;
 end;

this should work
```